# Consume multipart request and forward as it to third application using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data

Front end is sending multipart form-data to Spring boot back end.

Is it possible to take this form-data and forward it to third application using spring boot rest template?

Currently, I am reading the form-data using @ModelAttribute. Then I am creating an HttpEntity with headers set as Multipart form-data and sending it using postForEntity.
However, I am facing issues while posting the Multipart file. So was wondering if I could take the request object and pass it as it is.

```
public HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> getHttpEntity(SubmitModel model) throws IOException {
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    map.add("json", model.getDocMetadata());
    MultipartFile files[] = model.getFile();
    for(MultipartFile file : files) {
        String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        File storeFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Resource fileRes = new FileSystemResource(storeFile);
        map.add("file", fileRes);
    }

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
    return requestEntity;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you upload the error stake?